# object to int casting on bitwise operation

Tags: c++, casting, bit-manipulation, xor

Hi guys this is my second time trying to interprete a C++ code (I'm a very newbie), I just want to make sure the meaning of C++ code below :

```
//| Get other endpoint of an edge  |  
//+--------------------------------+    
inline Node *Node::NextNode( Edge *next)  
   {  
   return (Node *) ((!next) ? NULL : ( (int)next->node[0] ^ (int)next->node[1] ^ (int)this ) );  
   }
```

is the code means to convert/cast objects hold in `next->node[0]` and `next->node[1]` to  int, and apply XOR operator to their bit values? and use the result as reference to `Node*` in return? 
thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: What are you expecting from this code?  Seems to me that casting 3 node pointers to ints, XOR'ing together and casting them back to a Node pointer will just give you junk

Comment: unless Nodes are allocated in a really special way.. you shouldn't digest this code if you're really a beginner.

Comment: It could be valid if the pointers were members of an array and this was an oblique way of calculating offsets.

Comment: If so, there are better ways to do it and probably a beginner should avoid this kind of code!

Comment: additional inf , the constructor of Edge is : `node[2]`->Nodes at endpoints of edge ,`Edge *pself[2]`->points to edge[] entry of node at endpoint,`Edge *next;`-> next two fields are for inclusion into doubly-linked lists moves[], chains[], etc) `Edge *prev;` `Edge *parent;`->points to parent chain-edge. Meanwhile construct of Node class  is  `Edge *edge[4];`->ptrs to connecting edges ,`Node *neigh[4];`->ptrs to neighbors. Mainly the code is about a grid contains array of box n each boxe constructed by 4 edges, I want to know which node is the nextNode of an edge is it node[0] or node[1]?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. (Though you ignored the ternary and the cast of this as well)

Keep in mind that unless you're very careful, such code is likely to have undefined behavior and be nonportable (for example, on x86-64, pointers are bigger than ints.)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess here is that `Edge` represents an edge between two `Node`s and is defined like the following

```
struct Edge {
    Node *node[2];
    // perhaps other fields
}
```

Both elements in `node` must be filled in. They may point to different nodes or, crucially, may point back at the same node.

What's more, `Node::NextNode()` must only be passed an `Edge` object that contains the node itself as one of the two `node` elements on the edge (or may be passed NULL).

Given that, this function is basically equivalent to

```
if (next) {
    if (next->node[0] == next->node[1]) return this;
    if (next->node[0] == this) return next->node[1];
    return next->node[0];
}
return NULL;
```

although as Antimony has pointed out, it's actually buggy in that it's casting to `int` which will behave incorrectly on any architecture with pointers larger than ints. And of course the function will behave incorrectly if you don't satisfy the invariants (e.g. you pass in an `Edge` that doesn't contain the node as either of its two `node`s).

Comment: yes,your interpretation's correct, Edge constructor is `Node *node[2];`->Nodes at endpoints of edge ,`Edge *pself[2]`->points to edge[] entry of node at endpoint,`Edge *next;`-> next two fields are for inclusion into doubly-linked lists moves[], chains[], etc) `Edge *prev;` `Edge *parent;`->points to parent chain-edge. Meanwhile  class edge(): `Edge *edge[4];`->ptrs to connecting edges ,'Node *neigh[4];'->ptrs to neighbors. Mainly the code is about a grid contains array of box n each boxe constructed by 4 edges, I want to know which node is the `nextNode` of an edge is it node[0] or node[1]?

Comment: and sorry, i'm bit confused about `this` , is it `node [0]` or `node[1]` ?

Comment: @ignisc3: Either one. That's the beauty of this. If one of `node[0]` or `node[1]` contains `this` then `this ^ node[0] ^ node[1]` will produce the value of the node that isn't `this`. And if both contain `this`, then it will produce `this` as the output. Think about it this way: if `node[0]` was `this` then you'd have `this ^ this ^ node[1]`, and `this ^ this` is clearly `0` and `0 ^ node[1]` is clearly `node[1]`.

Comment: sorry I have another question , here's the code : `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)   prev = (Edge *) ( (int) prev ^ (int) edge[i] );  return prev;`
do you mind explain to me how the teration works in this situation?and what is the final result of `return prev`? thanks in advance

Comment: @ignisc3: In that snippet, `edge` is an array of 4 values. Where did that array come from? And what is `prev` initialized with?

Comment: the snippet is an internal method of class `Node`: `inline Edge *Node::NextEdge( Edge *prev)` and one constructor of class `Node` is `Edge *edge[4];` i guess the `edge` comes from that constructor, no initialization of `prev`, in implementation `prev` is "a currently visited edge"

Comment: @ignisc3: I'm really not sure what that snippet is doing then. I'd have to see the whole code, not just little unformatted snippets. But it certainly looks weird. XORing pointers together typically returns garbage. All I can think of is if one of the elements of `edge` is the same as `prev`, and two more elements are the same thing (e.g. an edge that connects back to the same node), then this method will return the last `Edge` (i.e. the one that isn't `prev` and that doesn't connect back to itself).

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is correct.  This is very strange code.  One normally doesn't xor some integers together and treat the result as a pointer.

Look in the header file near the declaration of `node` and see what is says about what the field encodes.  If there isn't such a comment, run away from this code ASAP!

Comment: It looks like a XOR linked list, the problem is that there's no guarantee that `int` is big enough to store pointers.

Comment: I agree.  There could be such a guarantee we're not seeing, though, like an assert of `sizeof(int)==sizeof(intptr_t)` in the `Node` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)next->node[0] ^ (int)next->node[1] ^ (int)this
```

Given next->node[0] and [1] are clearly pointers, seen in isolate an XOR of them provides a meaningless value (except in the trivial case that they're equal), but given the expectation that XORing with `this` produces something meaningful, I'd assume that one of the node[] values is known to be `this`, such that we're left with whichever is not `this`.  In other words, for this scenario the code's probably meant to be equivalent to:

```
next->node[next->node[0] == this]
```

(or if that's a bit cryptic, you may prefer `next->node[next->node[0] == this ? 1 : 0]`; in C++ `true` converts to 1 and `false` to 0 when a number's expected)

The comment in the source code *"Get other endpoint of an edge"* seems to support this: it's apparently known that `this` is one endpoint, and the code finds the "other" endpoint....

Another scenario that would yield a valid pointer is when both `node[0]` and `node[1]` are the same, in which case `this` is returned.  If this scenario is intended to be supported (and not just a coincidence of implementation), then the suggested simplifaction above will fail.  You could try:

```
next->node[0] == next->node[1] ? this : next->node[next->node[0] == this]
```

If there's any doubt about whether run-time data could include two identical node values, then this substitution's safer.

As others have pointed out, the code assumes that the pointers are of the same size as `int`, which is pretty nasty!  I won't discuss that as it's done to death elsewhere, but do keep it in mind.

Comment: thanks, 2nd scenario is correct, there's a time where node[0] and node[1] are the same, ur explaination makes it clearer, but I get confused with `this` keyword, is it `node[0]` or `node [1]` ??
this's how it assign node[0] and node[1], for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
      int j = 0;
      `for (; node[i]->edge[j] != NULL; j++);`  
      `node[i]->edge[j] = &edge;`
       `edge.node[i] = node[i];`

Comment: "Is `this` `node[0]` or `node[1]`?".  If node[0] and node[1] are the same, then it doesn't actually matter what they are because we'll use `this` and ignore their content (i.e. keep looping around on the current node).  If they differ, exactly one must be `this` - we'll follow the other one.  So, basically we go to any other node we can find, but if there's just nowhere else to go we "revisit" the current node.

Comment: 'exactly one must be `this`' , I think that one is `node[0]` , it's clearer for me now, thank you..thank you so much :)

Comment: @ignisc3: you're welcome, and good luck - looks like gnarly code!

Comment: sorry I have another question , here's the code : `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)   prev = (Edge *) ( (int) prev ^ (int) edge[i] );  return prev;`
do you mind explain to me how the teration works in this situation, and the final result of `return prev` , thanks in advance

Comment: @ignisc3: the overall effect is that `prev = prev ^ edge[0] ^ prev ^ edge[1] ^ prev ^ edge[2] ^ prev ^ edge[3]`.  In that, as `prev ^ prev` = 0, it simplifies to `prev = edge[0] ^ edge[1] ^ edge[2] ^ edge[3]`.  I'm afraid I can't guess what use that is without studying the entire code, and honestly - when code's that cryptic you're probably better off throwing it away and using `std::list`.